# Emoji Keyboard - How to add emoji keyboard like whatsapp in ReactNative?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I want to add an emoji keyboard like WhatsApp for my chat application, I tried react-native-emoji-board and some more are just pickers they really don't act like a keyboard with TextInput.

Somebody, please suggest to me if there is a library that works with TextInput or even there is any way to open the system emoji keyboard on a button click.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Their is a package o npmjs.org called React Native Emoticons
you can find it on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-emoticons
this should help you typing some emojis